# How to get paypal Pay key from paypal

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using paypal adaptive payments API to make a sale from my site.

I want to use it to the point where I can click a button on my site to initiate a payment, my site makes a call to the Paypal server and I get the PayKey returned. According to tech documentation I have read setup the whole process but nothing come through.

My Form that needs to be submitted is:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" name = "paypal_form"> 
                <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light"> 
                <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="insert_pay_key">       
                <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal">    
        </form>
```

and I have a javascript trigger that starts the lightbox when the submit button is pressed:

```
var dgFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'submitBtn' });
```

So if I press the button, the lightbox opens as required, and i simple got the paykey once and let other process do. please help